# Transistor current calculation

Tags: voltage, transistors, current

Why is the current through 1K resistor higher than Ib (Base current) even though the base-emitter path is less resistive than 1K?

[Schematic](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2012.050203812241895%2054%205%2043%0Av%2096%20336%2096%20128%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20192%20128%20192%20240%200%205000%0Ar%20192%20240%20192%20336%200%201000%0At%20192%20240%20320%20240%200%201%200.5567525022528119%200.6232162297381136%20100%0Ar%20320%20224%20320%20128%200%202000%0Aw%20320%20128%20192%20128%200%0Aw%20192%20128%2096%20128%200%0Aw%2096%20336%20192%20336%200%0Aw%20192%20336%20320%20336%200%0Aw%20320%20336%20320%20256%200%0A)

Comment: Why do you think that the base-emitter path would be "less resistive" than 1k?

Comment: My understanding is, once the Base-Emitter is forward biased it's like a short circuit. Sol it has the lower resistive path.

Comment: What's the voltage across the 1 k resistor?

Comment: A "short circuit"? The B-E path is a forward-biased pn-junction. Do you know how the current-voltage characteristic looks like?

Comment: You are lacking understanding of transistor technology, all transistors are build to have higher I collector than Ibase, this is why they are amplifiers. Please start from the beginning. This will not help you.

Answer (score 1):

The NPN transistor in your circuit needs about 0.6V across B-E before any significant amount of current will flow through that junction,

As such there needs to be at minimum about 600uA flowing through that resistor to reach that voltage,

Once your past that point, the B-E junction still has a voltage vs current curve, so there is some point where the amount of current the B-E junction is taking in, and the resistor drop the same voltage, for you this happens to be at 250uA flowing into the base, with a junction voltage of 0.623V,

Comment: Thanks for your answer.